# MVC or Net Core framework to speed up productivity in web application in visual studio

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

I am looking for a best framework as base that make everything I need is ready to start my web application in MVC5 or MVC6 (net core) in visual studio :
such as user managements ,roles  and languages

Comment: So what's your programming question?

Comment: @AntonToshik: I think he wants to have a base project.

Comment: Simply, use ASP.NET Core (there's no such thing as MVC6). MVC 5 is only LTS at this point. There's no active development there any more. Additionally, ASP.NET Core is *vastly* more performant than ASP.NET MVC. It's not even a contest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many templates for this. For example ASP.NET Boilerplate, AdminLTE. You can visit this link to refer more. Hope to help, my friend.

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Samples

https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE

Comment: Resist the temptation to jump right into some framework wrapped around a framework, such as something like ASP.NET Boilerplate. Most everything you need is available out of the box with ASP.NET Core, and the majority of what something like Boilerplate adds to it is unnecessary bloat you don't actually need. Get your feet wet with ASP.NET Core, itself, first and then you will at least have a basis to evaluate if something like Boilerplate adds anything worthwhile for you.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: Maybe you're right. But I just suggest him some options to refer :))